# Angular js page reload error during pending http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh, angular-promise, angular-http

In a single page angular App during the time of ongoing http get requests (before the page is fully loaded) , if i reload the page , all the http request errorcallbacks are called . I use google chrome.
Save the below code in an html file and reload the page just after it is open to reproduce the problem.
This breaks the whole page because it shows alerts from all the APIs being called.
If there are 50 pending http requests i get 50 error alert on reloading the page during the http request.I donot want to remove the alert from the errorCallBack function of the http get.  If i reload the page after  all the ajax http requests are completed then it doesnot show any error.
Please help me get around this problem.

```
<div ng-app="iceApp" ng-controller="allCharacterController as myCharacter">

<input type="text" id="search1" ng-model="search.name">

  <div ng-repeat="book in myCharacter.character | filter : search">
    {{book.name}}
  </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var myApp = angular.module('iceApp', []); 

 myApp.controller('allCharacterController',['$http',function($http) {

 var main = this;
 this.character=[];
 this.baseUrl = 'https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/';

  // there were 50 pages to get data from thats why i have made a loop


 this.allCharacters = function(){
 for(i=1;i<50;i++){

 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: main.baseUrl+"characters?page="+i+"&pageSize=50"
  })
  .then(function successCallback(response) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
      console.log(response.data);
      if(response.data.length>0){
          main.character.push.apply(main.character,response.data);
              }


    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
      alert("some error occurred. Check the console.");
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

}// end load all blogs
  this.allCharacters();

}])
</script>
```

ps: I am really struck on this. Please help me get around it. Above is a minimalistic question i have made to reproduce the problem.
 Actual web Application i have been working on : https://codemachin.github.io/gameofthrones/

Comment: Use Alerts and other modal dialogs sparingly as they are disruptive. Their sudden appearance forces users to stop their current task and focus on the dialog content. Sometimes this is a good thing but **most of the time it’s unnecessary and quite often it’s very annoying.** Consider alternatives such as inline expansion and toasts.

Comment: *I am still searching for a better solution that does show even a single alert because the reload is intentional.* The simplest solution is to remove the alert. What error is occurring and why does the user need to be interrupted?

Comment: It was a mistake i corrected it afterwards. I actually meant ---_i am still searching for a better solution that **does not** show even a single alert because the reload is intentional_

Comment: The website is already hosted on github, i have given the link also. Take my git repository link too . here it is https://github.com/codemachin/gameofthrones

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem **in the question itself.** That code should be…
 **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Got it @georgeawg. See i have updated the question and prepared a question that reproduces the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
BookService.getAllHouses([i])
.then(function successCallback(response) {

  if(response.data.length>0){
      main.all.push.apply(main.all,response.data);
          }
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
  alert("some error occurred. Check the console.");
  console.log(response);
  //IMPORTANT
  throw response;
});
```

When a `.catch` handler fails to re-throw an error, it **converts** a rejected promise to a successful promise.

---

One approach is to reduce the number of alerts is to use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to provide a single rejection handler.

```
this.allHouses = function(){
    var promiseList = [];
    for(let i=1;i<12;i++){
      var promise = BookService.getAllHouses([i])
        .then(function onSuccess(response) {        
          if(response.data.length>0){
              main.all.push.apply(main.all,response.data);
          }
          return response.data;
      });
      promiseList.push(promise)
    };

    return $q.all(promiseList)       
      .catch( function onRejection(response) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
          alert("some error occurred. Check the console.");
          console.log(response);
          throw response;
    });
}
```

With [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all), if any of the promises is settled with a rejection, the resulting promise will be rejected with the rejection value of the first rejected promise.

This example improves the `allHouses` function by having it return a promise that can be used for further chaining.

Comment: Tried your solution goerge but it didn't help. Just the same. If i reload the page before it has completely loaded, it it showing errors from all the pending http get calls in google chrome.

Comment: Thanks george, that definitely reduces the no of errors by hell of a lot. I will be using it for now, but i am still searching for a better solution that does not show even a single alert because the reload is intentional. Also i am getting a new type of error in console log   .....VM491 angular.min.js:118 
Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: "", headers: function}......Is this a common problem or i am the only one facing it as i am not able to find a proper solution over the internet